# Run-time error '1004' 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I am having this error when I execute my command.

I've tried solving but still have same error. Any idea how can I solve this problem.

**Piece of code** :

```
Dim col As Long

col = Range("type").Column 'this line produces an error
```

Here's the complete code :

```
Sub refresh()

Dim imin As Long, col As Long, imax As Long, column As Long, numRow As Long
Dim myLine As Integer

myLine = 2
numRow = Sheets("merge").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If numRow > myLine Then

    imin = Range("type").Row + 1
    col = Range("type").Column

    With Sheets("temp")
        .Cells.Delete
        If Sheets("merge").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row >= myLine Then
            Sheets("merge").Range("C" & myLine & ":E" & Sheets("merge").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Range("A1")
        End If

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        For column = 1 To 3
            If .Range(Fct_LetCol(column) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then
                .Range(.Cells(1, column), .Cells(.Range(Fct_LetCol(column) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, col)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, header:=xlNo
                imax = .Range(Fct_LetCol(column) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                tridata Sheets("temp"), Range(Fct_LetCol(column) & "1:" & Fct_LetCol(column) & imax), Range(Fct_LetCol(column) & "1:" & Fct_LetCol(column) & imax), xlAscending, xlSortNormal, xlGuess
            End If
        Next column
    End With

    With Sheets("selection")
        imax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
        If imax >= imin Then .Rows(imin & ":" & imax).Delete
        Sheets("temp").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("temp").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Cells(imin, col)
        Sheets("temp").Range("B1:B" & Sheets("temp").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Cells(imin, col + 2)
        Sheets("temp").Range("C1:C" & Sheets("temp").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Cells(imin, col + 4)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        imax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
    End With

    Sheets("temp").Cells.Delete
    Sheets("selection").Activate
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

Else
    msg = MsgBox("Error", 64, "Error")
End If   

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a named range with the name of "type" ?

Comment: Yes the range that contains"type" is B19

Comment: Furthermore, (if you have that named range "type") it may have multiple columns, so try `col = Range("type").Cells(1,1).Column` or `col = Range("type").Cells(1,Range("type").Columns.Count).Column`
And it'd be best to add a sheet reference because if that named range isn't on the `ActiveSheet` it may throw an error! ;)

Comment: Is "type" defined at worksheet level? or workbook ? is it in the same sheet this code is in ?

Comment: '"type" is defined at workbool level

Comment: I just defined "type" name range to cell "B19" at workbook lever, tested your code and got 2 (column B), can you edit your post and add a screen-shot of how you defined "type" ?

Comment: Is the range B19 **named** "type" or **containing** "type"?

Comment: B19 is named "type" but contains a different value

Comment: Could you maybe add a screenshot of your name definitions, so that there wont have to be any further questions about this. :) You can use imgur.com for uploading pictures

Comment: You defined `col` twice in your complete code.

Comment: I have attached a picture of the excel sheet containing "type".

Comment: and the second col was a mistake, I corrected it to column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running this modified code:

```
 Sub refresh()

Dim imin As Long, col As Long, imax As Long, numRow As Long
Dim myLine As Integer

myLine = 2
numRow = Sheets("merge").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If numRow > myLine Then

imin = range("type").Row + 1
col = range("type").Column

With Sheets("selection")
    imax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
    If imax >= imin Then .Rows(imin & ":" & imax).Delete
    Sheets("temp").range("A1:A" & Sheets("temp").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Cells(imin, col)
    Sheets("temp").range("B1:B" & Sheets("temp").range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Cells(imin, col + 2)
    Sheets("temp").range("C1:C" & Sheets("temp").range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Cells(imin, col + 4)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    imax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
End With

Sheets("temp").Cells.Delete
Sheets("selection").Activate
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

Else
  msg = MsgBox("Error", 64, "Error")
End If

End Sub
```

I found that running the procedure while having active sheet that is different from the one where the range `"type"` is in, leads to a reference error in the range `"type"` (check your name manager). So be sure to set the active sheet to the one where `"type"` is in before assigning values to `imin` and `col`, or go with `imin = Sheets("RelevantSheetName").Range("type").Row + 1` etc.

Comment: thanks for helping. I have specified the sheet, now it works !!